# Creating a method that merges 2 arrays into one sorted array in ascending order in Java

Tags: java, arrays

For part of an assignment, I have to create a method that merges 2 arrays into one sorted array in ascending order. I have most of it done, but I am getting a bug that replaces the last element in the array with 0. Has anyone ever run into this problem and know a solution? Heres my code:

```
     public static OrderedArray merge(OrderedArray src1, OrderedArray src2) {

         int numLength1 = src1.array.length;
         int numLength2 = src2.array.length;
         
         //combined array lengths
         int myLength = (numLength1 + numLength2);
        // System.out.println(myLength);
         OrderedArray mergedArr = new OrderedArray(myLength);
         
         //new array
         long[] merged = new long[myLength];
         
         //loop to sort array
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;
         int k = 0;
         while (k < src1.array.length + src2.array.length - 1) {
             if(src1.array[i] < src2.array[j]) {
                 merged[k] = src1.array[i];
             i++;
             }
             else {
                merged[k] = src2.array[j];
             j++;
                 
             }
            k++; 
            
         }
         
         //loop to print result
         for(int x = 0; x < myLength; x++) {
             System.out.println(merged[x]);
         }
         return mergedArr;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxSize = 100; // array size
//      OrderedArray arr; // reference to array
        OrderedArray src1 = new OrderedArray(4);
        OrderedArray src2 = new OrderedArray(5);


        
//      arr = new OrderedArray(maxSize); // create the array
        
        
        src1.insert(1);  //insert src1
        src1.insert(17);
        src1.insert(42);
        src1.insert(55);
    
        
        src2.insert(8); //insert src2
        src2.insert(13);
        src2.insert(21);
        src2.insert(32);
        src2.insert(69);
        
        OrderedArray myArray = merge(src1, src2);
```

This is my expected output:

```
1
8
13
17
21
32
42
55
69
```

and this is my current output:

```
1
8
13
17
21
32
42
55
0
```

Comment: What steps have you done to debug your code and your problem? Please show the steps and the results of this in your question. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error. Check loop conditions, whether you chose < versus <= correctly, and whether you applied things like `- 1` correctly

Comment: I updated the code a little bit. When I used the debugger, it told me that this specific line "if(src1.array[i] < src2.array[j])" is the problem. I think the problem is when one of the arrays gets incremented past it's actual size but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While merging two arrays you are comparing them, sorting and merging but what if the length of two arrays is different like Array1{1,3,8} and Array2{4,5,9,10,11}. Here we will compare both arrays and move the pointer ahead, but when the pointer comes at 8 in array1 and at 9 in array2, now we cannot compare ahead, so we will add the remaining sorted array;

Solution:-

(Add this code between loop to sort array and loop to print array)

```
        while (i < numLength1) {
            merged[k] = src1.array[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while (j < numLength2) {
            merged[k] = src2.array[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
```

Comment: Yes this was the main problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your main question, the length of your target array is `src1.array.length + src2.array.length`, so your loop condition should be one of:

- `while (k < src1.array.length + src2.array.length) {`
- `while (k <= src1.array.length + src2.array.length - 1) {`

Otherwise, you will never set a value for the last element, where `k == src1.array.length + src2.array.length - 1`.

But depending on how comprehensively you test the code, you may then find you have a bigger problem: [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). Before trying to use any array index, such as `src1.array[i]`, you need to be sure it is valid. This condition:

```
if(src1.array[i] < src2.array[j]) {
```

does not verify that `i` is a valid index of `src1.array` or that `j` is a valid index of `src2.array`. When one array has been fully consumed, checking this condition will cause your program to fail. You can see this with input arrays like `{ 1, 2 }` & `{ 1 }`.

This revision of the code does the proper bounds checks:

```
if (i >= src1.array.length) {
    // src1 is fully consumed
    merged[k] = src2.array[j];
    j++;
} else if (j >= src2.array.length || src1.array[i] < src2.array[j]) {
    // src2 is fully consumed OR src1's next is less than src2's next
    merged[k] = src1.array[i];
    i++;
} else {
    merged[k] = src2.array[j];
    j++;
}
```

Note that we do not need to check `j` in the first condition because `i >= src1.array.length` implies that `j` is a safe value, due to your loop's condition and the math of how you are incrementing those variables:

- `k == i + j` due to parity between k's incrementing and i & j's mutually exclusive incrementing
- `k < src1.array.length + src2.array.length` due to the loop condition
- Therefore `i + j < src1.array.length + src2.array.length`

If both `i >= src1.array.length` and `j >= src2.array.length` then `i + j >= src1.array.length + src2.array.length`, violating the facts above.

A couple other points and things to think about:

- Be consistent with how you refer to data. If you have variables, use them. Either use `numLength1` & `numLength2` or use `src1.length` & `src2.length`. Either use `myLength` or use `src1.array.length + src2.array.length`.
- Should a `merge` method really output its own results, or should the code that called the method (`main`) handle all the input & output?
- Is the `OrderedArray` class safe to trust as "ordered", and is it doing its job properly, if you can directly access its internal data like `src1.array` and make modifications to the array?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to merge two arrays without repetitive items in sorted order is that insert both of them into treeSet just like the following:

```
  public static int[] merge(int[] src1, int[] src2) {
        TreeSet<Integer> mergedArray= new TreeSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < src1.length; i++) {
            mergedArray.add(src1[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < src2.length; i++) {
            mergedArray.add(src2[i]);
        }
        return mergedArray.stream().mapToInt(e->(int)e).toArray();

    }

public static void main(String[] argh) {
    int[] src1 = {1,17,42,55};
    int[] src2 = {8,13,21,32,69};
Arrays.stream(merge(src1,src2)).forEach(s-> System.out.println(s));
  }
```

output:

```
1
8
13
17
21
32
42
55
69
```

Comment: Arrays are not like sets. They can contain duplicate items. How many items are in your sorted array if `src1 = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }` and `src2 = { 1, 1 }`? If it's not 8 items, the solution is incorrect.

Comment: This solution was specifically for the example in question. 
This is not a general solution.

Comment: If the problem is to sort these two specific arrays, then the best implementation is to hardcode the answer: `return new long[] { 1, 8, 13, 17, 21, 32, 42, 55, 69 }`. Obviously that is _not_ the problem. The ask is for a general solution, and the first sentence of this answer claims to be giving a general solution. Anyway, if the goal is to use libraries, read the Javadoc for `Arrays.sort(...)`: "It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array." Definitely don't box primitive types or lean on set semantics for a sort.

Comment: you didn't get my point. I mean the solution was for arrays with non-repetitive items. concatenate two arrays are not the best solution because it needs an array with space and time complexity of O(N+M). then sorting arrays in the best case is O(log(N+M)) then the final complexity is  O(log(N+M)) + O (N+M).  but in treeSet case complexity is O(logN) + O (logM).

Comment: How do you purport to merge two arrays without allocating an array of size M+N? That array is part of the very contract of the method. You _must_ know that your `TreeMap` with M+N items (boxed, btw) amounts to _extra_ memory and work on top of the needed M+N sized array. And besides, I assume you have looked at the implementation of `Arrays.sort` and how it outperforms O(X log X) time on partially sorted data? Just populating your `TreeSet` is O(X log X) time & O(X) memory. Even _just your `merge`s last line_ uses more time and memory than `new int[]` + 2x `System.arraycopy` + `Arrays.sort`.